# additional special query in TypeBox feathersjs not working correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs, typebox

I use feathersjs v 5.0.8 with TypeBox for mongoDB schema. In my schema I have a nested json object after which I'm doing finding data. I added additional special query to schema in this way:

```
[
  querySyntax(messageQueryProperties),
  // Add additional query properties here
  Type.Object({'businessRegisterEntityID.NIP': Type.String()}),
  Type.Object({})
]
```

when my query is like this: { query: { 'businessRegisterEntityID.NIP': 1234567890 }}
the app is working correctly but when my query not contain businessRegisterEntityID.NIP field, then I receive an error:

```
error: Data: [
  {
    instancePath: '',
    schemaPath: '#/required',
    keyword: 'required',
    params: { missingProperty: 'businessRegisterEntityID.NIP' },
    message: "must have required property 'businessRegisterEntityID.NIP'"
]
```

I want searching a data by empty query like this: { query: {}} and after nested object like this: { query: { 'businessRegisterEntityID.NIP': 1234567890 }}

How to prepare TypeBox mongoDB schema with additional special query?